# My Copying code doesn't copy entire row value

Tags: excel, vba

Please go download my problem file by this link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2n3BIKH9iL5bFhiNjZid3YzLVE/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is that when I click the copy that time only copy 26 ROW where my data was shown 38 ROW. I can't find why this kind of problem arises

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Sheets("List").Range("AG3:AG" & Sheets("List").Range("A65536").End(xlShiftUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("List").Range("J3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: It is best if you present the code here.

Comment: If you edit your post and place your code in the post - it will aid readers thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the copy from

```
Sheets("List").Range("AG3:AG" & Sheets("List").Range("A65536").End(xlShiftUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

to

```
Sheets("List").Range("AG3:AG" & Sheets("List").Range("AG65536").End(xlShiftUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy
```

Modifications
1- Changed A65536 to AG65536. Checking wrong column, unless it was intentional. Beacuase of this it is always returning 26 rows.
2- Change your SpecialCells criteria to look for Numbers in AG formulas.

Comment: i have make problem in here
"Modifications 1- Changed A65536 to AG65536"
i just need only visible Number, not Formulas Thanks Bro.